# Executing an application after a period of time

Tags: c#, .net, batch-file

I'm writing a small app that needs to be executed once a week.
I could write it as a service that runs constantly but only executes the task that I need it to once a week, but that seems like overkill.

Is there another way of executing an application once every x period of time?
I'm looking for a solution that doesn't involve user interaction.

Answer (score 3):

You can always use [Windows Scheduled Tasks](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569).  They can be ugly, but effective.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [Windows Task Scheduler](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569).  It was designed with this scenario in mind.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Windows Scheduler for planning execute app once a week.

Answer (score 2):

Under windows you can use the [at utility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/At_(Windows)).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Windows Task Scheduler in the Control Panel.  Just set up a task to run your application on the specified day.  You can even tell it to run as a certain user if you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you need full control on the process (result values, parameters to be provided, etc), I would suggest you to create your own task scheduler, where you can use the cron algorithm to schedule the time you want execute your task.
I know it may sounds overkill to create a service to run once a week, but if you make a generic scheduler, you will be able to reuse your schedule for other purposes.

I created this scheduler in the past, and it has been used for years in production. I implemented the cron algorithm in .Net, based in the open source algorithm that one developer (Artif Aziz) wrote. Check out my blog for more information on this:

[CronTab schedule parser algorithm](http://blog.robertolopes.com/2010/11/17/crontab-schedule-parser-algorithm/)

If you think in a higher level (enterprise level), you could consider buying Control-M, one of the most powerful scheduler tools I have ever used, however it is quite expensive.

Cheers!

Roberto.