# building a desktop application to run periodically

Tags: c#, .net

I built a C# desktop application that will run on some time trigger.

I want to consult with you what should be my 'driver' project?

A winService? How should I set the trigger?

Comment: Have you looked into Windows Scheduled Tasks?

Comment: What does the desktop app do?  Why can't the user start it manually?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Executing an application after a period of time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007814/executing-an-application-after-a-period-of-time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The accepted answer here is a little confusing. The simplest way to achieve what you want is to use the built in Windows Task Scheduler to launch your application at a specified time each day.  There is no need to write a Windows Service.  In fact, it doesn't even make sense to talk about running a service under the task scheduler, as by definition a service runs continuously.

However, a service could be another way of achieving what you need.  The service could define a timer which fires once a day and performs any tasks required.  Be aware that a service cannot have a UI - it just runs in the background.  It can also be a little more challenging to write than a desktop application.

More about services here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d56de412(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can create a windows service and then set it to run using the Task Scheduler. This would enable you to run your application at a certain time everyday, depending on how you have set it up. Although the downside of this is that a windows service cannot have a UI. But if you just want the Task Scheduler to run your actual desktop application then just do that.

Comment: If you create a service, why would you need to schedule it? Just have it start on boot and make it decide when to run.

Comment: If using the task scheduler, then there is no need to go as far as creating a service, as a console application will do.

Comment: @Mikey Cee, are you sure? What is the downside of winservice over consoleApp ?

Comment: @crashmstr if you don't want the service to be running constantly then use the scheduler to decide when to run the service/app. But you are right you could start the service on boot and get it to sit and wait until XX:XX before it performs any tasks.